# Transposing HTML table containing values of arrays with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, transpose

I have a table which looks like this:

[image]

I want the table to have 2 columns and multiple rows instead of having 2 rows and multiple columns. I want it to look like this instead:

[image]

Currently, the table is created by taking values which are inside of two arrays, `milestone` and `milestoneDate`. Then, it is appended to a div with the id `meilensteine`. In this example, the array `milestone` consists of `1. MS: Beginn,2. MS: Start,3. MS: Meilensteine,4. MS: Testung` while `milestoneDate` consists of `06.09.2021,07.09.2021,08.09.2021,09.09.2021`

This is the HTML part:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <strong><u>Meilensteine</u></strong>
    </div>

    <p></p>
    <div id="meilensteine">
    </div>

    <p></p>
</div>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
var cycleArr = [milestone, milestoneDate];

var strTable = "";
if (cycleArr.length != "0"){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < cycleArr.length; i++) {
        strTable += "<tr>"
        for(var j = 0; j < cycleArr[i].length; j++) {
            strTable += "<td>";
            strTable += cycleArr[i][j];
            strTable += "</td>";
        }
        strTable += "</tr>";
    }
} else {
    strTable = "Es gibt derzeit keine Meilensteine. Definieren Sie gerne die Meilensteine für das Projekt hier.";
}
$('#meilensteine').append(strTable);
```

I experimented a bit, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with a specific trick!

## 1. First, make a template using template literals in javascript:

```js
const tableRowTemplate = `<tr><td>Stuff for column 1</td><td>stuff for column 2</td></tr>`;
```

## 2. Take the two arrays and dynamically add content to the template:

```js
const milestone = ['1. MS: Beginn','2. MS: Start','3. MS: Meilensteine','4. MS: Testung']
const milestoneDate = ['06.09.2021','07.09.2021','08.09.2021','09.09.2021']
for(let i = 0; i< milestone.length; i++){
    const tableRowTemplate = `<tr><td>${milestone[i]}</td><td>${milestoneDate[i]}</td></tr>`;
}
```

## 3. Append this template inside the table and see it in action:

```js
const milestone = ['1. MS: Beginn', '2. MS: Start', '3. MS: Meilensteine', '4. MS: Testung']
const milestoneDate = ['06.09.2021', '07.09.2021', '08.09.2021', '09.09.2021']
for (let i = 0; i < milestone.length; i++) {
  const tableRowTemplate = `<tr><td>${milestone[i]}</td><td>${milestoneDate[i]}</td></tr>`;
  document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += tableRowTemplate
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <strong><u>Meilensteine</u></strong>
  </div>

  <p></p>
  <div id="meilensteine">
  </div>

  <p></p>
  <table id="table"></table>
</div>
```

## I hope this helps to solve your query.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const milestones = [ "1. MS: Beginn", "2. MS: Start", "3. MS: Meilensteine", "4. MS: Testung" ];
const milestoneDates = [ "06.09.2021", "07.09.2021", "08.09.2021", "09.09.2021" ];

let tdms = "", tdmsd = "";
for (let i=0; i<milestones.length; i++) {
  tdms += `<td>${milestones[i]}</td>`;
  tdmsd += `<td>${milestoneDates[i]}</td>`;  
}
document.getElementById("msrow").innerHTML = tdms;
document.getElementById("daterow").innerHTML = tdmsd;


let tr = "";
for (let i=0; i<milestones.length; i++) {
  tr += `<tr><td>${milestones[i]}</td><td>${milestoneDates[i]}</td></tr>`;  
}
document.getElementById("twocols").innerHTML = tr;
```

```html
<h3>2 rows</h3>
<table id="tworows" border="1">
 <tr id="msrow"></tr>
 <tr id="daterow"></tr>
</table>

<h3>2 columns</h3>
<table id="twocols" border="1"></table>
```